# Update graph in cytoscape.js: node positions not updated

Tags: nodes, cytoscape.js

I have used the following line :

```
 cy.json({ elements: treeData });
```

in order to update the data in my graph (using cytoscape.js). The graph has now the new data but the nodes are in the positions of the previous ones. How can i fix that? I do not have specific positions i want to get the default ones based to the new nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

The problem with the false positions probably originates to the cy.json() not updating the graph before the layout finishes, try this out with your code:

```
cy.json({ elements: treeData }); 
cy.ready(function () {
    var layout = cy.layout({ name: 'breadthfirst', directed: true, padding: 2 }); 
    layout.run();
});
```

---

The function [`cy.json()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.json) has two functionalities, first the export of a graph, second the import of a graph. When using the import, you can specify what you want to import:

- cyjson = the whole exported json
- { elements: ... }
- { style: ... }

You want the nodes with their positions, so you have to use cyjson. Here is an example for the whole thing:

```js
var json;
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        content: "data(id)",
        "text-valign": "center",
        "text-halign": "center",
        height: "60px",
        width: "100px",
        shape: "rectangle",
        "background-color": "data(faveColor)"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        "curve-style": "bezier",
        "control-point-step-size": 40,
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "Top",
          faveColor: "#2763c4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "yes",
          faveColor: "#37a32d"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "no",
          faveColor: "#2763c4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "Third",
          faveColor: "#2763c4"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "Fourth",
          faveColor: "#56a9f7"
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: "Top",
          target: "yes"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "Top",
          target: "no"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "no",
          target: "Third"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "Third",
          target: "Fourth"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "Fourth",
          target: "Third"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  layout: {
    name: "dagre"
  }
}));
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function() {
  json = cy.json();
});
document.getElementById('load').addEventListener('click', function() {
  cy.json(json);
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 85%;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.3.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js">
  </script>
  <!-- cyposcape dagre -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <b id="save" style="cursor: pointer; color: darksalmon">Save graph</b> / <b id="load" style="cursor: pointer; color: darkmagenta">Load graph</b>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have already done that, but i want a function for updating dataset. So, i have a function updateTree in which i have the following code:
    cy.json({ elements: treeData });
    var layout = cy.layout({ name: 'breadthfirst', directed:  true, padding: 2 });
 layout.run();

Comment: You should add that piece of code before someone answers your question...